# How can I create an expression that narrows a discriminated union?

Tags: typescript

Sometimes I like to create discriminated union types inline like so:

```
type MyDiscriminatedUnion =
  | { type: 'create'; name: string }
  | { type: 'update'; id: string; name: string; };
```

How can I write a type expression that narrows to `{ type: 'update'; id: string; name: string; }` by using/knowing `type: 'update'`?

By type expression, I mean something I can assign to `type` e.g.

```
type Update = /* ??? */
```

Comment: You would write `if(someObject.type === 'update') ...` to narrow the type of `someObject`. See [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

Comment: Ah, I think i need to clarify more. I'm looking for a type expression. Thank you!

Comment: OK, in that case `Extract<MyDiscriminatedUnion, {type: 'update'}>` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey that works! post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Well, there's definitely another question which already has essentially this answer, so it would be more appropriate to mark it as a duplicate, if I can find one it's a duplicate of.